# How to specify the location of the distros used by docker based on WSL2

Tags: windows, docker, wsl2

I want to specify which WSL distros are going to be used to run docker on windows, or at least I want to be able to specify the location in which such distros are located.

I have disks c and d, and Windows is installed on c, which is a SSD with less space. I want to keep the docker engine running on WSL distros stored on d. I could successfully create a WSL Ubuntu 20.04 distro in d by following these [instructions](https://medium.com/@vpraharsha3/installing-wsl-distro-to-a-different-custom-location-30d101f04113).

However, when I install docker on Windows, it creates 2 additional WSL distros:

```
wsl --list
Ubuntu-20.04 (Default)
docker-desktop-data
docker-desktop
```

I have no control over how these distros were created. Is there a way to specify their locations or even
better, make docker use my Ubuntu-20.04 distro as its backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to move the distros by using the tutorial I found [here](https://blog.iany.me/2020/06/move-wsl-to-another-drive/). When docker for windows uses WSL2, it creates 2 distros (docker-desktop-data, docker-desktop). It is possible to move both distros by using the following commads:

```
wsl --export docker-desktop-data data.tar
wsl --unregister  docker-desktop-data
mkdir docker
wsl --import  docker-desktop-data docker data.tar

wsl --export docker-desktop docker.tar
wsl --unregister   docker-desktop 
mkdir docker-base 
wsl --import   docker-desktop  docker-base  docker.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

#### make docker use my Ubuntu-20.04 distro as its back end

> 7. When Docker Desktop restarts, go to Settings > Resources > WSL Integration.
>
> - WSL Integration will be enabled on your default WSL distribution.
> - To change your default WSL distro, run `wsl --set-default <distro name>`
>
>   For example, to set Ubuntu as your default WSL distro, run `wsl --set-default ubuntu`.
>
> 8. Click Apply & Restart.

Source [Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/)

So try running:

```
wsl --set-default Ubuntu-20.04
```

in step 8 above.